# get the position of some letters in a string using javascript .match()

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, match

I have the following string:

```
  var strg = "strEeTofSesameS";
    console.log(strg.match('e'));
```

and I want to get the position of second `"e"` from string and third `"s"` and I want to count no matter if my string contain big letters or small letters.

I prefer to use `.match()` because will be better for my script.

why I cannot simply give the letters `console.log(strg.match('e','s'));` ? seems that is not allowed :|. I think will be better to return an array with all letters e and s from string with their positions.

Comment: What is your question? Is it why you cannot simply give the letters ...? Reading documentation about `match` should give a clue on that.

Comment: "I prefer to use `.match()` because [it] will be better for my script." obviously it's not *better* because it doesn't do what you want. Use `indexOf`.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes I know indexOf() and search() but I want to use .mach() and regular experision to identify my letters...

Comment: @mcmwhfy, good luck with that. Enjoy reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @zzzzBov great answer, thank's!

Comment: `match` does not return positions but an array or null. Why do you think `match` will benefit you?

Comment: @trincot exactlly, return an array with matched elelemts, for example if I use a regular expresion like [A-z] will return an array with all letters of my string. I have used:  var kk = "AaBbCcDd".match(/[A-z]/g); 
     kk.forEach(function(value,index){
     console.log(value,index)
});

Comment: Oh, that makes your question different, where you wrote *"I want to get the position of...*". Could you update your question?

Comment: Is `.match(/[es]/gi).forEach(...)` what you are looking for? It just matches `e` or `s`. The `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: @trincot post your answer to accept it and to get the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
var strg = "strEeTofSesameS";
strg.match(/[es]/gi).forEach(function (letter, index) {
  console.log(index, letter); // an "e" ("E") or an "s" ("S")
});
```

It just matches `e` or `s`. The `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive.
The *index* identifies the sequential number of the match.